# Is this a homeomorphism with $\,[-1,1]$?

Tags: general-topology

From the set $S=\{(x,|x|):x\in[-1,1]\}$ we define $\,p(x,y):S\to [-1,1]$ by $\,p(x,y)=x$ is a homeomorphism right?

The projection map contains, this is clearly bijective, inverse also exists and continue. Am I right?

Comment: You might want to avoid confusing $p$ (the map) with $p(x,y)$ (the real number).

Comment: Yes, $\rho$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Note that this is quite a general concept:

Given a continuous function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ between topological spaces (in your case this is the mapping $[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto |x|$) you have an induced map $G(f):X \rightarrow X \times Y, x \mapsto (x,f(x))$ which is continuous with image the graph of $f$. Restricting the projection $X \times Y \rightarrow X$ to this subspace gives you a continuous inverse for $G(f)$, hence $G(f)$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and the graph of $f$.